# Extract Market from tag

Tags: postgresql, function

I need to extract the **"Market"** from the **"Tags"**. Below are sample tags : 
**"distinct_ypa_us_synd_skimag"
"distinct_ypa_say_us_enhanc_d2u_search"
"distinct_ypa_say_fr_enhanced_d2e_search"**

I need **"us"** from first and second tag. and **"fr"** from third tag. i have hundred of tags which have different market names in it. so i need search and extract in PostgreSQL.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (?)

```
with tags(name) as(
select 'distinct_ypa_us_synd_skimag' union all
select 'distinct_ypa_say_us_enhanc_d2u_search' union all
select 'distinct_ypa_say_fr_enhanced_d2e_search' 
)

select * from (
    select name, unnest(string_to_array(tags.name, '_')) unn from tags
) t
where unn in ('us', 'fr') -- here is "Market" list
```

[demo](http://rextester.com/TCX14450)

Comment: Thanks for your Prompt reply @Oti Shavadze. Its works. 
But can you please do like this : 
   select tag_name, substring(tag_name,end_of_text,position_of_searching_text) 
  from
  ( 

  select tag_name,position('u' IN tag_name) as position_of_searching_text,position('s' IN tag_name ) as end_of_text from distinct_tags 
)t 

NOTE: I have multiple markets 
('us', 'fr','de','it','au','ca','dk','es','mx','nl','no','se','ss','uk')